# Listing Array Issue

Tags: php

I am calling a webservice and I am getting a complex object back.  I need to display variables reg_no, opening_inventory_weight.

```
RESULT:-
object(stdClass)#12 (3) { 
    ["TxnErrors"]=>  object(stdClass)#13 (0) { } 
    ["TxnStatus"]=>  bool(true) 
    ["headers"]=>  object(stdClass)#14 (1) { 
        ["RPMHeader"]=>  array(1) { 
            [0]=>  object(stdClass)#15 (7) { 
                ["opening_inventory_weight"]=>  int(1001) 
                ["prepared_by"]=>  string(5) "James" 
                ["reg_no"]=>  string(7) "5000005" 
                ["reporting_period"]=>  string(19) "2010-02-01T00:00:00" 
                ["rsid"]=>  int(49) ["status"]=>  string(1) "D" 
                ["web_user_id"]=>  string(1) "0" } } } }
```

I am calling it like

```
 $result = call_search_existing_manufacturer();
 $rows = array();
 foreach ($result->RPMHeader as $data)
    { 
   $rows[] = array( 
      $data->reg_no, 
      $data->opening_inventory_weight,
      $data->status
     );
     }
```

But its not working. Any Idea what am I missing?  Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be

```
 $result = call_search_existing_manufacturer();
 $rows = array();
 foreach ($result->headers->RPMHeader as $data)
    { 
   $rows[] = array( 
      $data->reg_no, 
      $data->opening_inventory_weight,
      $data->status
     );
}
```

Comment: `$rows[] = (array) $data` achieves the same and keeps the keys intact, but I understood the OP wants to display certain values, not put them into an array.

Answer (score 1):

Your result dump isn't esay too read, so I may be wrong, but it looks like RPMHeader is part of headers field, so you should access it like

```
$result->headers->RPMHeader
```

Comment: `$result->headers->RPMHeader[0]->reg_no;`